# How to call disableAutoStyling() in angular2 onsen framework

Tags: angular, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I am new to angular2 and onsen ui framework. I want to use IOS style in both Android and IOS devices. I can see examples to call `ons.disableAutoStyling()` in JS to force devices to use IOS style. But I am not able to call this function in Angular2. Its giving error. I also tried `(<Element>document.querySelector('ons')).disableAutoStyling()` but same error.
Could you please help me here.

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: Its showing error message -  Property "disableAutoStyling' does not exists on type Element.